# How to create an infobox field which accepts multiple article-name entries and links to those articles?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm building a mediawiki infobox.  I'm using the standard table based infobox as opposed to importing the various templates and CSS functionality, and extensions that Wikipedia is now using.

One of the fields in the infobox is a link to various wiki categories.  I'd like to keep the linking code in the template, so the source article can just list the category names as perameter values for the infobox.

For example, my template currently contains

```
 <tr>
 <th>Some Categories</th>
 <td>[[:Category:{{{category_name}}}|{{{category_name}}}]]</td>
 </tr>
```

This works fine if I enter the category name on the source article in my infobox declarations as:

```
| category_name = Cat-1
```

In this case, the article displays an infobox, with a link to the Cat-1 category.

However I can't find how to include multiple category entries in the source article, and allow them to link to each one separately.  The articles which use this infobox can have from one to eight of these categories to declare.

Do I need to import all of the wikipedia style CSS infobox templates in order to achieve this, or can it be done with a simple table-based infobox?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add as many template parameters as the maximum number of category names you want to pass to the template and to [test for their being defined](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Template#Parameter_definition_with_explicit_or_implicit_parameter_name)

So your template code might be something like

```
 <td>[[:Category:{{{cat1}}}|{{{cat1}}}]]<!--
 -->{{#if: {{{cat2|}}} |, [[:Category:{{{cat2}}}|{{{cat2}}}]] |}}<!--
 -->{{#if: {{{cat3|}}} |, [[:Category:{{{cat3}}}|{{{cat3}}}]] |}}</td>
```

Etc. This was a common strategy before the Scribunto/Lua templates, which can just loop through data.